# How to get detailed error for contains deep in Karate?

Tags: api, automation, karate

while using `contains deep` for nested JSON object assertion. It is showing the JSON object having mismatch and not displaying the actual value where error has been encountered. For ex in expected JSON here we changed Name from John to Dave.

The assertion was successful but not showing the detailed reason for it.In case of huge JSON object it will be difficult to identify which key value pair is responsible for the error.

Is there any way to log the detailed error message in this case?

[image]

Comment: please try the 1.0 / RC version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - if you still don't like it, consider contributing code (or look for another framework ;)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried the new RC version to get the detailed error and it's giving better detailed report. But one thing I noticed when we mention API request URL in Background and path in the scenario It's not concatenating the URL with path. For which we have to include URL and Path in Scenario itself. Is this the new way we have to adopt or we can expect some changes.
And I am loving Karate, so currently not looking for another framework. Thank You :)

Comment: no one else has reported this problem you describe so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue